# G-Mail style drag & drop for inserting images in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload, ckeditor

How can I enhance **CKEditor** to support drag & drop of an image **from a user's desktop** into the content of the CKEditor textbox? It would have to upload the image to the server in the background, and insert a link to the image once the upload has finished. The resulting path of the image on the server does not matter (it could be a GUID for all I care).

Certainly not an easy task, and I would be more than willing to purchase such a plugin, however I cannot find any plugins that currently do this. Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about implementing such a plugin? I've looked around quite a lot today, but the best I've found is this [dropfile plugin](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5692), unfortunately, it does not appear to work in CKEditor 3.0. Thanks for any help.

Edit

I just watched this video, which shows CKEditor doing exactly what I want, however he doesn't mention how to set this up:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVInjn51VYw

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the guy that made the movie actually made a plugin for CKEditor: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.nl/2012/06/drag-and-drop-uploads-in-ckeditor.html